# value matching in Antlr v4

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to create a parser for a logic I'm using.
The expression I have a Pb with is of the form : 
Ag ( s1 , SC( s3 , s2 , p) ) .
I want to make sure that s1 = s3 . 
However s1 is a random String defined as a

```
VAR_NAME : [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*;
```

So the Rule is something like this :

```
s : 'Ag' '(' VAR_NAME ',' 'SC' '(' VAR_NAME ',' VAR_NAME ',' pathformula ')' ')';
```

And I need the first and second VAR_NAME to be equal !

Is there like a tag to force s1 and s3 values to be the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate to fail the rule if the two variables are not the same.  The basic form is:

```
rule : x=VAR_NAME y=VAR_NAME { $x.equals($y) }? ; // presuming Java backend
```

Labels are convenient to distinguish like rule elements - otherwise you could use the rule element names directly.